# Not returning focus to previously focused window

Tags: unity-2d, window-management, focus

This has been bothering me a lot. When closing a window, the system does not give the focus to the previously focused window. Let me give an example.

Right now, I'm working with Google Chrome and it is focused (active). I decide to open up nautilus and check a file. When I'm done with nautilus, when I close it, it should automatically return the focus to Google Chrome (previously focused window), but it doesn't. No window is focused, not even desktop.

Is there a solution for this problem?

note: I'm using Unity 2D, but I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: What has focus when you close Chrome?

Comment: Hmm. I'm using Lubuntu. To test, I'm responding via this comment using Chrome but I also have a text editor (Leafpad) open. I'm going to alt-tab from Chrome to Leafpad, type something into Leafpad, save it, and then close Leafpad (with Alt+spacebar, C). I expect that Chrome will be the active window and that I can just continue typing this comment. And that is just what happens.

Comment: @EvanCarroll When I close the secondly opened program, nothing has focus. I guess the desktop does. Any ideas?

Comment: @vasa1 So are you saying that yours works correctly? :/

Comment: But this is with Lubuntu. That's uses another DE. But yes, with it appears that focus returns to the last used window. I can also just "see" it because I've themed the window manager (Openbox) to have the title bar and title text look quite different in the window that has focus when compared to other windows that aren't in focus.

Comment: @vasa1 Yeah you're right. It's a different desktop environment. I don't know why this is happening in unity. I hope there's a solution for this and someone knows it..

Comment: Does this happen with other utilities other than Chrome?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes it does.. With all programs

Comment: This is certainly a bug. It didn't always do this, but it does hurt the efficiency of using Ubuntu.  I have this problem with 13.04. haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out what the problem was.

I was using "Glx-Dock / Cairo-Dock" and it was stealing the focus on every window close. I couldn't find a solution or even a single bug report on the net, so I just uninstalled it and now I'm fine.

And BTW, thanks for the down votes. I'm wondering how ridiculous my problem was to receive down votes :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 after installing Gnome Desktop (ubuntu-gnome-desktop) and configuring cairo-dock 3.4.1 to start on login. Additionally, I also had the problem that some application windows did not receive focus after I started them and started under the currently active window (so called 'pop under').

I traced the problem to the usage of cairo-dock's Desktop->Notification Area Old. It was working fine under the Unity desktop. After disabling this module the focus issue was resolved. Guess, that's why its called 'Notification Area Old'.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use compiz "Window Rules" to avoid focusing cairo-dock: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1339646&p=9565169#post9565169

Comment: Could you provide some specific details and steps for the OP to follow in your answer besides a link?